# C# — How to collect a selection of files in the active window of Windows File Explorer?

Tags: c#, windows-explorer, solidworks, microsoft-file-explorer, solidworkspdmapi

I'm creating an add-in for my company's product data management "vault" which is integrated into Windows File Explorer. I've successfully created a custom File Explorer Context Menu command called SW Quick View, available only from within the Vault. However, I can not figure out how to collect the selected files in the active Explorer window (so that I can get their file paths) and right click the selection to run the SW Quick View option in the context menu pop-up.
[Some visual context (AXC_VAULT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0huD.png)

The only way I've been able to collect a selection of files is through the OpenFileDialog class. This leads to a rather clunky workflow where you need to right click anywhere in File Explorer (whitespace/folder/file makes no difference) select SW Quick Viewer, an OpenFileDialog box pops up, and then you make your selection and click Open.

---

I just want the user to be able to use their one (of likely many) windows of File Explorer, highlight files, right click, select SW Quick View, which then will collect all paths of the selected files and run the logic with no pop-ups or further user input required.

---

My working code:

```
    public static void OpenWithQuickViewer()
    {
        string[] fileNames;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileNames = ofd.FileNames;
            foreach (string filePath in fileNames)
            {
                // Confirmed working "SW Quick View" logic here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this for `OpenFileDialog` window or Windows Explorer selection?

Comment: I just edited the post restate my desires from the title after explaining the problem. I don't want to use `OpenFileDialog` I want to use Windows Explorer selection.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to automate 1.) the selection 2.) activating the RMB menu 3.) selecting your PDM command?  Do you already have the list of file names to be selected?

Comment: The reason I ask is that, assuming you have PDM professional, the API can be used to select multiple files already and run a custom routine. It already knows what's selected and passes that into the add-in when the command is selected from the RMB menu.

Comment: The user will manually select the files. The selection will be different every time based on the users needs. The user will manually select my PDM command from the RMB menu.

Comment: To add a bit more context for those familiar with Solidworks and EPDM, SW Quick View just opens one or more native Solidworks files in detailing mode, large design review, or view only, depending on if it’s a part, assembly, or drawing file. However, I excluded this info and code because this is all irrelevant to the question posed. The question posed is about how collect the file paths of selected files though the Windows File Explorer where my method is being called as an alternative to OpenFileDialog.

Comment: Using context menu in Windows Explorer, the selected files will be sent to application as command line argument (I guess). Look at `args` in `Main(string[] args)`.

Comment: @Kraz, I was asking PDM specific questions because when you select a bunch of files and then choose the RMB menu command, it sends the IDs of the selections as an array to the function that handles hooked events in the API.  So, with that said, did you make the "SW Quick View" using a PDM Add-In that you wrote? If so, that same PDM add-in can handle the file paths. If not, disregard this I guess.

Comment: @i486 Since the add-in is a software extension, it has to be a Class Library file and thus, no `Main(string[] args)`. But for a standalone .exe, this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @bigcrazyal. From your comment I was able to get the desired result.

---

To further expand on bigcrazyal's comment and show a working example:

I used the `ref EdmCmdData[] ppoData` from the default structure of the Solidworks Enterprise PDM add-in as outlined [here](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/api/epdmapi/csharpaddins.htm)

```
private void OpenWithQuickViewer(EdmCmdData[] ppoData)
    {
        ISldWorks sldWorks = new SldWorks();
        IEdmVault5 vault = new EdmVault5();
        vault.LoginAuto("AXC_VAULT", 1);

        IEdmFolder5 folder = (IEdmFolder5)vault.GetObject(EdmObjectType.EdmObject_Folder, ppoData[0].mlObjectID3);

        foreach (EdmCmdData item in ppoData)
        {
            string filePath = $@"{folder.LocalPath}\{item.mbsStrData1}";
            IDocumentSpecification docSpec = sldWorks.GetOpenDocSpec(filePath);
            string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

            if (fileExt == ".SLDDRW")
            {
                docSpec.DetailingMode = true;
            }
            else if (fileExt == ".SLDASM")
            {
                docSpec.ViewOnly = true;
            }
            else if (fileExt == ".SLDPRT")
            {
                docSpec.ViewOnly = true;
            }
            IModelDoc2 modelDoc2 = sldWorks.OpenDoc7(docSpec);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. I do have a couple of notes. 1) although it's highly likely you're in the same folder when you're making your selections, it's best to get the parent folder ID with each iteration of the loop instead of just once at the beginning. 2) You don't need to make a new vault object and log in to the vault. The vault object is passed to `OnCmd(ref EdmCmd poCmd, ref EdmCmdData[] ppoData)` as `poCmd.mpoVault`. It's already logged in and you can pass this to your function as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I'll be sure to add those optimizations. =]